# Xcode swift: My unwind segue doesn't add to my tableView

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have been loosely following the Apple Developer tutorial for the "Meal Tracker" app (found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1) and while I built the app in its entirety before, and it worked, I am trying to make a modified version, and I'm hitting an obstacle. Everything has worked until I tried to implement a "save button" to add a new item to my table view that uses an unwind segue. The segue works perfectly and all of the information that I want to pass prints to the console appropriately, but for some reason my new cell won't add to the table view.

Here is the code for "prepare for segue":

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if saveButton === sender {
        let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
        let date = dateLabel.text ?? ""
        let price = priceTextField.text ?? ""
        let balance = 100.00

        // Set the purchase to be passed to PurchaseTableViewController after the unwind segue.
        purchase = Purchase(name: name, date: date, price: price, balance: balance)
    }
}
```

And here is the code for "unwind to purchase list":

```
@IBAction func unwindToPurchaseList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? AddPurchaseViewController, purchase = sourceViewController.purchase {
        // Add a new purchase.
        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: purchases.count, inSection: 0)
        purchases.append(purchase)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tableview begin updates and end updates

```
@IBAction func unwindToPurchaseList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? AddPurchaseViewController, purchase = sourceViewController.purchase {
    // Add a new purchase.
    let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: purchases.count, inSection: 0)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    purchases.append(purchase)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
}
```